# matplotlib.use required before other imports clashes with pep8. Ignore or fix?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pep8

I have a Python script that starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from cmath import rect, phase
```

It works like a charm, but my editor complains: `E402 module level import not at top of file [pep8]`.

If I move the `matplotlib.use("Agg")` down, the script will not work.

Should I just ignore the error? Or is there a way to fix this?

I'm aware that PEP8 says that this is only a suggestion and it may be ignored, but I'm hoping that there exists a nice way to initialise modules without breaking PEP8 guidelines, as I don't think I can make my editor ignore this rule on a per-file-basis.

(I'm using Atom with linter-pylama.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution depends on the `linter` that is being used.

In my case I am using `pylama`

The manual for this `linter` suggests adding `# noqa` to the end of a line containing an error you wish to suppress.

Other linters may have different mechanisms.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, `matplotlib` now has a `switch_backend()` function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
# import other modules
matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend('Agg')
```

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend

But beware, you run the risk of exploding:

> Switch the default backend. This feature is experimental, and is only
>   expected to work switching to an image backend. e.g., if you have a
>   bunch of PostScript scripts that you want to run from an interactive
>   ipython session, you may want to switch to the PS backend before
>   running them to avoid having a bunch of GUI windows popup. If you try
>   to interactively switch from one GUI backend to another, you will
>   explode.
>
> Calling this command will close all open windows.

It works nicely for me with `matplotlib` 1.3.1 but not with 1.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

Another, not so nice, solution, but one that I've temporarily deployed for an environment with `matplotlib` 1.0.0, is to use a wrapper module.

In`matplotlib_agg.py`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

In other files:

```
import matplotlib_agg
# other imports
```

Not sure whether this is worth it. I would prefer to ignore it in the editor; but I couldn't get the one I use (PyCharm) to ignore just this one particular violation of PEP8 E402.