# Disable Tensorflow/Numpy Deprecation Warning Messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Running my Python 3.7.4 app that uses `tensorflow` v1.14.0 causes a large list of deprecation warnings to appear. The following code clears up most of it.

```
try:
    from tensorflow.python.util import module_wrapper as deprecation
except ImportError:
    from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation_wrapper as deprecation
deprecation._PER_MODULE_WARNING_LIMIT = 0
```

However, none of the warnings are removed. Updating `tensorflow` to v2.x is not an option right now.

How can these messages be removed?

**Warning messages:**

```
/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/x/foo/dnnlib/tflib/tfutil.py:34: The name tf.Dimension is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Dimension instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/x/foo/dnnlib/tflib/tfutil.py:74: The name tf.variable_scope is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variable_scope instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/x/foo/dnnlib/tflib/tfutil.py:128: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.
```

Comment: is setting conservative log level (ERROR) an option? it will suppress all warnings, not only deprecation ones

Comment: @Marat Yes, how can we set that?

Comment: @Marat `tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)` does not appear to work

Comment: that's what I was going to suggest. There is also native Python logging, can you prepend `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)` as well?

Comment: Tried `import logging`, `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)` but no luck >_<

Comment: I think the warnings are being thrown in a module `dnnlib` that my script is importing. Not sure if running these code to suppress warnings in my app can propagate the effects into the imported modules.

Comment: it should, unless they use non-default logger with explicitly set level

Comment: one last attempt: these warnings come from type annotations. Try setting tf loglevel and deprecation limit before importing dnnlib

Comment: In addition to the last coment, `from __future__ import annotations` should have a similar effect (Python 3.7+)

Answer (score 9):

You can ignore all "FutureWarning" warnings by putting the following code at the beginning of your scripts ([source](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-fix-futurewarning-messages-in-scikit-learn/)):

```
from warnings import simplefilter 
simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

Please note that you have to put those lines before any other imports as some of those might already import dependencies on their own.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

The issue that brought me here was actually for a recent numpy deprecation warning coming from code in `tensorboard`, but I expect that the principles comes to bear on the question in the OP as well.

### Approach

Adding the following before any `tensorflow` imports will suppress developer-directed [`DeprecationWarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#DeprecationWarning) arising from [that specific module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63980460/3780389) (DeprecationWarnings are ignored by default, but they might be turned on, e.g., by QA tools; use [`FutureWarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FutureWarning) instead if the deprecation warnings are directed at end-users):

```py
from warnings import filterwarnings  # noqa
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',
                        category=DeprecationWarning,
                        module='tensorflow')  # noqa
```

### Notes

- If you are developing a multi-file package, you might considering putting the filter code at the top of your `__init__.py` file (after any `__future__` imports).
- Auto-formatters (like `black` or `autopep8`) may push these lines *after* the offending import. Since I'm use an autopep8-on-save trigger in VSCode, I also needed to add the `# noqa` to the import and filter lines so that they were not moved (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57067521/3780389)). To avoid needing to squelch linting error for the following imports, another option is to move the warning filtering lines to a separate python file and then import that from `__init__.py` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40257363/3780389)).
- (Of course, for my `tensorboard` issue, I used `module='tensorboard'` instead.)