# Python how to filter specific warning?

Tags: python, warnings, suppress-warnings

How to filter the specific warning for specific module in python?

## MWE

```py
ERROR:

cross_val_score(model, df_Xtrain,ytrain,cv=2,scoring='r2')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py:148: LinAlgWarning: Ill-conditioned matrix (rcond=3.275e-20): result may not be accurate.
  overwrite_a=True).T
```

## My attempt

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',module='sklearn')

cross_val_score(model, df_Xtrain,ytrain,cv=2,scoring='r2')

This works but I assume it ignores all the warnings such as deprecation warnings. I would like to exclude only LinAlgWarning
```

## Required Like

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category='LinAlgWarning', module='sklearn')
```

Is there a way like this filter specific warning?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the warning could be safely ignored and there is nothing in your code that needs to be fixed to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to pass category as a WarningClass not in a String:

```
from scipy.linalg import LinAlgWarning

warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=LinAlgWarning, module='sklearn')
```

Comment: There is no variable `LinAlgWarning`.  There has to be a different way here.

Comment: You need to import LinAlgWarning

`from scipy.linalg import LinAlgWarning`

`warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category= LinAlgWarning, module='sklearn')`