# Filtering PyTables PerformanceWarning with warnings.filterwarnings() fails

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

There are a number of answers on this website detailing how one can ignore specific warnings in python (either [by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979540/python-how-to-filter-specific-warning) or by [providing a regex to match a warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134795/how-to-get-rid-of-specific-warning-messages-in-python-while-keeping-all-other-wa)).

However, none of these seem to work when I try try to suppress `PerformanceWarning`s coming from PyTables.

Here's an MWE:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import warnings 
from tables import NaturalNameWarning, PerformanceWarning

data = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 'two'
} 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient = 'index') # mixed types will trigger PerformanceWarning

dest = pd.HDFStore('warnings.h5', 'w') 

#dest.put('data', df) # mixed type will produce a PerformanceWarning
#dest.put('data 1', df) # space in 'data 1' will trigger NaturalNameWarning in addition to the PerformanceWarning

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category = NaturalNameWarning) # NaturalNameWarnings ignored 
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category = PerformanceWarning) # no effect
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='.*PyTables will pickle') # no effect
#warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') # kills all warnings, not what I want

dest.put('data 2', df) # PerformanceWarning

dest.close()
```

Using a context manager doesn't help either:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=PerformanceWarning) # no effect
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='.*PyTables') # no effect
    dest.put('data 6', df)
```

Nor does using `warnings.simplefilter()` instead of `warnings.filterwarnings()`.

Perhaps relevant, here is the PerformanceWarning:

```
test.py:21: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed-integer,key->block0_values] [items->Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')]

  dest.put('data 2', df) # PerformanceWarning
```

Contrast this with the `NaturalNameWarning`, which doesn't come from the offending line in `test.py`, but from `tables/path.py`:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tables/path.py:137: NaturalNameWarning: object name is not a valid Python identifier: 'data 2'; it does not match the pattern ``^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$``; you will not be able to use natural naming to access this object; using ``getattr()`` will still work, though
  check_attribute_name(name)
```

This is with tables 3.7.0/python 3.8.10. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work in ipython terminal? Does it work in plain Python terminal?

Comment: Good question. I just tried and it turns out the `PerformanceWarning` shows even when running outside of JupyterLab (copy the above MWE to a file `test.py` and do `python3 test.py`; you will see `PerformanceWarning`s). So this probably doesn't have anything to do with JupyterLab. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @Corralien thanks. Any idea why the warning trace doesn't indicate that the warning is coming from pandas?

Comment: Yes. Pandas uses an utility function `find_stack_level()` to modify the level where the [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) is raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be confusing but the `PerformanceWarning` is not emitted by the `tables` package but by `pandas`:

Try:

```
from pandas.errors import PerformanceWarning
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import warnings 
from tables import NaturalNameWarning
from pandas.errors import PerformanceWarning

data = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 'two'
} 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient = 'index')

dest = pd.HDFStore('warnings.h5', 'w') 

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=PerformanceWarning)
    dest.put('data', df) # mixed type will produce a PerformanceWarning
    dest.put('data 1', df) # space in 'data 1' will trigger NaturalNameWarning

dest.close()
```

Only the `NaturalNameWarning` should remain in the above example.

Comment: Cool, this solved it. Why didn't the regex filter catch this? (`warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='.*PerformanceWarning')`?

Comment: Because you can't filter the warning name (only the message). The correct regex is `r'[\r\n]+.*performance'`